# Twilio outbound call function return error 500 `Url parameter missing`

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-functions

Here is my Twilio function:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

const twilioClient = context.getTwilioClient();

const to = event.to;
const from = event.from;


  twilioClient.calls
    .create({
      twiml: '<Response><Say>Ahoy, World!</Say></Response>',
      from: from,
      to: to,
      machineDetection: 'Enable',
    })
    .then((result) => {
      console.log('Call successfully placed');
      console.log(result.sid);
      return callback(null, 'success');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      return callback(error);
    });
};
```

I'm trying to make a outbound call which says a message when one picks up. I'm getting the following error:

```
  "status_code": 500,
  "content_type": "text/plain",
  "body": "Error: Url parameter is required."
```

What I'm missing is if I send `twiml` do I need a `url` too?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code snippet, it looks like you are using Twilio's Serverless Functions. By default, a new Service will use version 3.29.2 of the NodeJS `twilio` library. The ability to directly embed TwiML in the Call resource was first added in version [3.38.0](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/releases/tag/3.38.0). In order to fix the error, under "Settings & More" in the Services Console, select "Dependencies" and click "Edit" for the `twilio` library. The value can be updated to the latest version (as of today) which is [4.11.0](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/releases/tag/4.11.0). Once the dependency has been updated, you will need to run a "Deploy All" and then the code should work as expected.